# Recommended 2D Sprite engine for a Delphi board game?

Tags: delphi, opengl, sprite

Which are the choices I should look into for a Delphi sprite engine.

I am aware of

- GLScene
- Andorra 2D

anything else I am missing?

It is best if it relies on OpenGL. DirectX only solutions are not very welcome.

Comment: Found a nice article on the topic at http://delphihaters.blogspot.com/2009/10/delphi-playing-games.html

Comment: An excellent podcast on Pascal Game Development with lots of links to Pascal/Delphi game development engines: http://delphi.org/2011/10/pascal-game-development/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at [Asphyre](http://dev.ixchels.net/products/asphyresphinx/overview).  It's a 2D/3D Delphi framework that can use OpenGL, DirectX 7, DirectX 9 backends.

Comment: Yeah, I made the D2010 port some time ago. Should run under XE as well.

Comment: I started playing with Asphyre 4.1 a couple of weeks ago, it's pretty impressive, having greatfun with it so far.

Answer (score 3):

Some libraries for 2D graphics, I'm not sure if they are what you're looking for, but here we go:

AggPas is port of Anti-Grain geometry library: http://www.crossgl.com/aggpas/

Graphics32 is all around graphics library: http://graphics32.org/wiki/Main/Graphics32

GR32_Lines is based on Graphics32: http://angusj.com/delphi/gr32_lines.php

Answer (score 1):

There's also UnDelpiX, Hadron (was PyroGine), Phoenix, and others.
Have a look at the forums at [PascalGameDevelopment](http://www.pascalgamedevelopment.com/forum.php), there a forum for pretty much all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Opengl 2d engine 
[sites.google.com/site/boxdemi/](http://sites.google.com/site/boxdemi/)

Fast, simple and easy.

Git - [github.com/Dev-Demi/GLEngine2D](http://github.com/Dev-Demi/GLEngine2D)

Comment: Is there an english version on the website concerning OpenGL 2D Engine? I think both links would be more valuable if it's available.

Comment: I do not speak English. If there is anyone help me with a translation guide - will be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

For the record: maybe oldschool but still vastly used for game development is x-platform SimpleDirectMedia Library.
Is also has Pascal headers for it.

http://www.libsdl.org

http://www.freepascal-meets-sdl.net/