# Best GDI drawing approach

Tags: delphi, gdi

I am developing an interactive CD most of my life I wrote console applications writing something mostly graphical is akward for me.

So here is my approach :

I am drawing on the canavas using shapes and images the left and top position are stored in a file. Is there any easier approach ? I thought using shapes objects would simplify my work what do you guys think ?

Any examples are welcome.

If you consider this question subjective please vote for closing.

Comment: It is somewhat subjective. But in any case you'll probably better using a game library for this; see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060302/recommended-2d-sprite-engine-for-a-delphi-board-game/5060730) for an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way is to write an `OnPaint` handler (that is, listening to the `WM_PAINT` message) and drawing using the GDI.

Here are a couple of simple examples:

- [Moving triangles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7224075/282848)
- [Bouncing ball](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16446087/282848)

Drawing by moving controls is very awkward.

Comment: I started doing that but I must always check if I am in a clickable zone,using OnmouseMove and checking if the cursor is in a clickable TRect. Isn't that too cpu expensive, any ideas on how to check if I am in a clickable zone when the mouse moves ?

Comment: @opc0de: Modern CPUs are *very* fast, so in my experience, you shouldn't be afraid of adding a lot of code that runs often, as long as the code isn't expensive. Checking a small number of inequalities isn't expensive.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't specify a any version, I assume you're not wasting your time with an ancient Delphi, so maybe you should also take a look at **FireMonkey**.

That also opens the door to having your interactive stuff work on other platforms..

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [the Delphi GDI+ Library](http://www.bilsen.com/gdiplus/index.shtml) which I have used with success.  It's a wrapper around GDI+ which takes alot of the pain out of it.